# Is there a way to use array extensions in kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use Kaminari pagination with array data. I saw some stuff on their wiki but I am having problems with it. That's when I noticed a page showing [array extensions](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/models/array_extension.rb) for Kaminari. Anyone know if I could use this for my own arrays in my project somehow? And if so, could you show me how? I don't know if I need to extend my array class from this, or include it as a module, or what.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but looking at that code, maybe you could try something like

```
f = PaginatableArray.new
```

And then use this as your array, since it inherits everything from Array. Alternatively, there might be something with the following method in there:

```
self.paginate_array(array, options = {})
```

You might be able to do something like the following to translate your existing arrays.

```
a = Array.new
b = PaginatableArray.paginate_array(a)
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks like something like this just might work for you.